# C# | How do I create a new class with user input?

Tags: c#

Creating a new class with naming the class with user input

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee name");
       string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
       Employee [ inputName ] = new Employee();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a new instance of the class and assign the FirstName property like this:

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee() { FirstName = "Joe" };
```

or like this:

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
newEmployee.FirstName = "Joe";
```

or... if there's a rule that you shouldn't be able to make an instance of the employee class without supplying the first name, then you add a constructor to your class:

```
public class Employee
{
    private string firstName;
    public Employee(string FName) //constructor
    {
        firstName = FName;
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While this is helpful and likely what the user is ultimately trying to do, it's always better to ask for clarification rather than just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

use dictionnary, inputname as key and Employee as value

```
Dictionnary<String,Employee> employees = new Dictionnary<String,Employee>();
string inputname=Console.ReadLine();
employees[inputname]=new Employee();
```